# Can I use NetBeans with asp.net as an editor?

Tags: asp.net, netbeans

I want to design a site with asp.net (C#.net) and need an editor for my admin panel to add paper with picture etc., So I must use ckeditor, tinyMce or any other suggestions.

However one of my friends told me that I shouldn't use an editor in your site and use NetBeans (with asp.net plugins) instead.
Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you checked for asp.net plugins for NetBeans? I'm not seeing any on their plugins site... **[NetBeans Plugins](http://plugins.netbeans.org/)**. If you are using asp.net, start by looking **[here](http://www.asp.net/get-started)**...

Comment: Why did your friend say not to use one of the editors?

Comment: please see this link for asp.net plugin : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/85177/C-in-Netbeans)

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE to enable developers to create code, whereas ckeditor and tinymce are components to give site-users a WYSIWYG editor. So you can't exchange one for the other, unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather, no; currently it's not supported.

I've done some research (Google) but haven't been able to find any plugins. If this was possible there would be a Netbeans plugin for it.

[Have a look at this link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic4393.html&ei=s5tRUaP0Bcam0wXbi4CYCw&usg=AFQjCNFUV1Z9XBUJHkUGGB8OGJaTDE28Ww&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k)

You might want to ask your friend why he suggested using Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still working on a plugin .NET Core for NetBeans: https://github.com/Chris2011/DotNetCore-for-NetBeans. Still a long road to go but I'm on it.

Cheers

Chris